# youtube-dl set sample rate on mp3?

Tags: windows, audio, mp3, youtube, youtube-dl

I am using [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) and I'm using the following command:

`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 %dl%`

This appears to use 48000Hz sample rate by default.

I want to use 41000Hz because the default causes clipping.

How can I set it to 41000Hz?

Answer (score 2):

Since youtube-dl doesn't provide this you will have to use the post-processor argument option. This may depend on what your post-processor is, for ffmpeg it would be (using the -ar argument to set the audio rate):

`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 --postprocessor-args "-ar 44100" %dl%`

Answer (score -1):

Note that the answer has a typo, the argument passed to the postprocessor-arg should be `-ar` instead of `-r`. Also, I am assuming you meant 44100 Hz as a sample rate is is more standard than 41000.

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 --postprocessor-args "-ar 44100" %dl%
```

Comment: “Note that the answer has a typo” - So propose an edit to it that fixes the typo.